# Manipulate input stream data and send it to output stream efficiently

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I am currently making a basic http proxy that can have some text censorship.
When I was reading from the input stream, I was hoping to manipulate the text(i.e. replace or delete) of the byte array and transfer it to the output stream for the client. However, the input stream size from the server can be very large (>100MB). Are there any ways to do it efficiently?

Here is my snippet (without manipulating any data) when reading and sending data from the server to the client.

```
int count = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
while ((count = fromServer.read(buffer)) > 0){
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
    toClient.write(buffer, 0, count);
    fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
fos.close();
server.close();
client.close();
```

fromServer is the input stream from the server, fos is the file for caching purposes and toClient is the output stream to the client.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll probably want to use a BufferedReader. Since you'll have to decode to change any text and then rewrite/reencode with another BufferedWriter. If you are going to try and read byte[] then decode and modify the existing byte[], I don't think you'll save much performance, but you'll have a huge headache.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Matt here .

Without buffering, each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient.

For without manipulating your data I would suggest the following

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)
```

The following code snippet may help you in case of manipulation of data

```
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\output.xml"));
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\input.xml")), 32*1024*1024);
         int bytesRead = -1;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
         while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
             String strFileContents = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             System.out.println(strFileContents);
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
         fos.close();
         bis.close();
```

Manipulation in a String would be easy .